# Split and count AWK

Tags: awk, vcf-variant-call-format

I have file (VCF) as like this

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##FILTER=<ID=q10,Description="Quality below 10">
##FILTER=<ID=s50,Description="Less than 50% of samples have data">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
##FORMAT=<ID=HQ,Number=2,Type=Integer,Description="Haplotype Quality">
#CHROM POS     ID        REF ALT    QUAL FILTER INFO    FORMAT      NA00001
Chr02   259 .   A   .   20  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:1:0,1:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,26,23,75,33,33,33,47,52,49:23
Chr02   260 .   C   .   13  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:1:0,0:0,1:0,0:0,0:24,0,70,17,25,49,43,25,25,44:16
Chr02   261 .   C   .   13  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:1:0,0:0,1:0,0:0,0:24,0,194,18,25,49,44,25,25,45:16
Chr02   262 .   C   A   21  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/1:1:0,0:0,1:0,0:0,0:387,0,342,348,25,368,376,25,25,368:25
Chr02   263 .   C   .   24  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:0,0:1,1:0,0:0,0:541,0,529,495,29,556,508,29,29,499:29
Chr02   264 .   A   .   31  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:1,1:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,280,192,317,36,36,36,178,302,219:36
Chr02   265 .   G   C   25  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/1:2:0,0:0,0:1,1:0,0:255,414,0,328,284,29,284,29,351,29:29
Chr02   266 .   A   .   31  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:1,1:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,281,323,440,36,36,36,209,309,315:36
Chr02   267 .   C   .   24  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:0,0:1,1:0,0:0,0:595,0,541,481,28,567,512,28,28,512:
```

I need to split this file based on the number of lines(1000)  and count "0/1" from each file(splitted file).
For this purpose I splitted the files using this command

```
head -10 Chromosome02.vcf| tee header subset.1.VCF >/dev/null ; awk -v header="`cat header`" -v count=1 '( (NR>10) && !( (NR-1) % 2) ) { count++ ; print header >"subset." count ".VCF";} {print $0 >>"subset." count ".VCF";}' Chromosome02.vcf | grep “0/1”
```

But it is not working. Is there any way to do this without generating the split files ?

Expected output

```
Chromosome02
00
00
01
00
01
00
```

Comment: Sorry but your splitting out the file logic is NOT clear here. Is it number of every `1000` lines you want to create a new output file? OR is there any other logic there seeing any value from Input_file? Because your shown output isn't looking in series, kindly do add clear details in your question so that we could understand it better, cheers.

Comment: `Without splitting the files` do you mean to get the count for every 1000 lines or for every 990, as if you had added the header in front of every chunk?

Comment: If I split the file based on the above script will give 1010 lines includes the header. I just want to get the count (0/1) from each 1010 lines

Comment: so it is the count for every 1000 lines, let's forget the header, the fact is that you don't want to actually split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
tail -n +11 file | 
    awk -v n=1000 '/0\/1/{c++} NR%n==0{print c; c=0} END {if (NR%n!=0) print c}'
```

The tail command will exclude the headers from the file. Then we count the lines containing the pattern, but every N lines we print and reset the counter.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples and assuming that we need to count `0/1` in every `1011` lines and print them.

***With `tail` + awk`:***

```
tail -n +11 Input_file | 
awk '
FNR%1000==0{
  if(++count==1){ print "Chromosome02" }
  print total
  total=""
}
{
  total+=gsub(/0\/1/,"&")
}
END{
  if(++count==1){ print "Chromosome02" }
  if(total){ print total }
}'
```

***With only `awk`:***

```
awk '
FNR==11{
  start=1
}
start && ++line && line%1000==0{
  if(++count==1){ print "Chromosome02" }
  print total
  total=""
}
{
  total+=gsub(/0\/1/,"&")
}
END{
  if(++count==1){ print "Chromosome02" }
  if(total){ print total }
}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** This considers that OP's Input_file wants count `0/1` from whole line in case you want to check specific field then above substitution could be changed for specific field.

Comment: your answer is great. But for biological output file like vcf fasta sam bed gff; you can also explore bioawk (biological version of awk) which give you a better control. Like for the Qs there 11 comment rows; but it can be different also. This comment is just for your knowledge.